# How do I license a game engine?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

After researching something along the lines of "Game Engine Licensing" in the R&D Lab, I gained access to research an SDK (Software Development Kit). I created a new game engine with this feature in it, but nothing seems to have happened...

**How do I license my new engines, and what does that do for me?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Licensing a game engine will happen automatically for a period of time after creating a new game engine with the SDK selected as one of the engine elements.

You will receive a payment on a monthly basis for " SDK" in addition to any income from Grid (if you completed it) and game sales.

Answer (score -1):

When creating a game, click on the platform. If you have enough money, it will ask you to buy a license for the console. Click yes.

Comment: He's not asking how to license a console. He's asking how to license a game engine he created. It's part of a late-game option.