# What are the requirements to unlock "License Game Engines" research?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I've seem to have researched, done and released everything there is in the game except the licensing out engine. I've never got the research for it. Everything else is pretty much maxed out, all the research, most of the employee training and such. So I'm a bit lost...

The only thing that I might be missing is the perfect game achievement, there's always someone who will give it a 9 >_<

Answer (score 1):

I believe you unlock that research when you create 10-12 custom game engines. [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115994/how-do-i-license-a-game-engine) is a similar question with more information about them.

Comment: Really? I've gotten through game with like 6, 6th one being the ultimate one with v7 graphics and stuff >_>

Comment: If you create engines for specific genres you can reduce their cost (ex. a simulation game doesn't need celebrity voice acting), and integrate newer research as you go along. That will usually increase your scores as well. That's a good way to have a high number of engines.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Research Lab](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/R&D_Lab) and to create 10 [Custom Engines](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Custom_Game_Engine).

Here is more information: [Research Unlocks](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Research_Unlocks)